# Not able to Mock CDatabase Open function using google Mock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to mock an Open function present as part of the CDatabase Class by using Google Mock. Visual studio version: 2010
Below is the code snippet:

```
class TestRLanguage: public RLanguage, public ::testing::Test
{
};

class FakeDatabase : public CDatabase
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD5(Open_impl, BOOL(LPCTSTR lpszDSN, BOOL bExclusive,BOOL bReadonly, LPCTSTR lpszConnect,BOOL bUseCursorLib));

    BOOL Open(LPCTSTR lpszDSN, BOOL bExclusive = FALSE,
        BOOL bReadonly = FALSE, LPCTSTR lpszConnect = _T("ODBC;"),
        BOOL bUseCursorLib = TRUE) override
    {
        Open_impl( lpszDSN, bExclusive, bReadonly, lpszConnect, bUseCursorLib);
    }
};

// Test case for testing initialize function
TEST_F(TestRLanguage, initializeSuccess)
{
    FakeDatabase database;
    EXPECT_CALL(database, Open(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "ODBC;DSN=", FALSE)).Times(testing::Exactly(1));
}
```

I get the below error:

> ```
> error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'AddReference<const ::std::tr1::tuple_element<I,std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1,_Arg2,_Arg3,_Arg4>>::type>::type testing::internal::TuplePolicy<TupleT>::get(const std::tr1::tuple<_Arg0,_Arg1,_Arg2,_Arg3,_Arg4> &)'    c:\src\googlemockandtest\aqtsw\util\googletest\googletest-release-1.8.1\googletest\include\gtest\gtest-printers.h
> ```

Can anyone help me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. In my case it was related to the version of Google Test. I had the issue with version 1.8.1 -- "the last release supporting pre-C++11 compilers" (as stated [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases/tag/release-1.8.1%5D)). The issue was fixed with [pull request #1817](https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/1817). I am using HEAD of [branch 1.8.x](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/v1.8.x) now ([commit dea0216](https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/dea0216d0c6bc5e63cf5f6c8651cd268668032ec)) and the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your test:

1. you put in the `EXPECT_CALL` a method function, that is not a mock method
2. you do not call any method in your test.

This is a proper way:

```
TEST_F(TestRLanguage, initializeSuccess)
{

    FakeDatabase database;
    EXPECT_CALL(database, Open_impl(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "ODBC;DSN=", FALSE)).Times(testing::Exactly(1));
    database.Open(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Even after commeting the EXPECT_CALL, i see the same error error C2770: invalid explicit template argument(s). One observation is mocking any method with one or more parameters throws the above mentioned error. But if i try to mock any function which has no arguments, there is no compilation error. Below is the code.

Comment: //Working code 
class RLanguageMock: public RLanguage
{
public:
    RLanguageMock():RLanguage( ){};
    MOCK_METHOD0(CreateDatabase,  RDatabase*());
};
//Non-Working Code
class RLanguageMock: public RLanguage
{
public:
    RLanguageMock():RLanguage( ){};
    MOCK_METHOD1(CreateDatabase,  RDatabase*(bool));
};